# Get object clicked by mouseEvent in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

I have a scene made up of objects, each with a different position. I also have 2–4 pawns I'd like to move to the position of the object clicked, not to the position of the event.

I tried doing something like `event->pos()` but that gives me the coordinates of the event. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you using a QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView here, or a bunch of QWidgets?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I am using scene and view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you're looking for is [QGraphicsView::items()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#items-2).

Comment: That's perfect! One more question – I get an output like this: `(QGraphicsItem(this =0x10db434b0, parent =0x0, pos =QPointF(240, 240) , z = 0 , flags =  ( ) ) ,  QGraphicsItem (this = 0x10a7f9d00 , parent = 0x0 , pos = QPointF(240, 240) , z = 0 , flags =  ( ) ) `. How do I extract the pos (QPointF) values out of this?

Comment: OK, already figured it out :) Save it to a QList<QGraphicsItem *> and get to the values through a takeFirst item. Thanks!